# Return a value or null using LINQ in one line?

Tags: c#, linq

I have statements like this all over the place. Is there some way to do it all in one line ? Maybe something in C# 6.0 would help ? I just want to get the value if there is something there and if not then return a empty string or maybe NULL.

```
var item = ll.Fields.Where(x => x.FieldTitle == "Loan Amount");
if (item.Count() != 0) {
    LatestItem.VelocifyLoanAmount = double.Parse(item.FirstOrDefault().Value);
}
```

EDIT 1: It is a double though other times I need to get a string. I love how quickly I get help for my LINQ questions. My Excel VSTO addin questions get crickets :)

Comment: If you have statements like this then you have plenty of other issues in your codebase other than a lack of brevity.  What if your double can't be parsed?

Comment: You would probably be better off extracting a helper method rather than reducing to one line. But it's hard to be more specific without knowing the exact form of duplication

Comment: What is the type of `LatestItem.VelocifyLoanAmount`? `double` or `double?`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
var item = ll.Fields
    .Where(x => x.FieldTitle == "Loan Amount")
    .Select(x => (double?)double.Parse(x.Value))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is the following:

```
var item = ll.Fields.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FieldTitle == "Loan Amount")?.Value;
if (!double.TryParse(item, out LatestItem.VelocifyLoanAmount)
{
    // do your error case here
}
```

UPDATE: added C#6.0 syntax to shorten the syntax, and using the preferred `TryParse` instead for error checking.

UPDATE 2: if for some reason `double.Parse` is preferred (for instance if a wrapper is handling exceptions for a large piece of code), here is a shorter example.

```
LatestItem.VelocifyLoanAmount = 
    double.Parse(ll.Fields.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FieldTitle == "Loan Amount")?.Value);
```

Comment: what if item.FirstOrDefault() throws null exception?

Comment: @Aniket this shouldn't happen, since we've already checked that the IEnumerable `item` has at least one element.

Comment: @JohnCarpenter You're combining three checks here...a Where, an Any, and a FirstOrDefault.  Do you think that's the most efficient solution?

Comment: how do you know `item` is not of type `double?`

Comment: FirstOrDefault() won't throw an exception even if there is no items. The "OrDefault" portion of the code is what takes care of the no items portion. Typically that will return a null value if it is an object type.

Comment: Use TryParse() where appropriate to avoid unnecessary exceptions. Also check your null values if you're working with FirstOrDefault()

Comment: @NathanC trying to get `.Value` of a nullable type, if it's `null` will result in exception "Nullable object must have a value"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Select` to project the objects in the collection to `double?` and return `FirstOrDefault`

```
double? parsedFirstValueOrNull = ll.Fields
    .Where(x => x.FieldTitle == "Loan Amount")
    .Select(i => (double?)double.Parse(i.Value))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

The cast `double?` is necessary, otherwise `FirstOrDefault` will return 0.0 for empty collection, which might be ambiguous.

Comment: what if double.Parse(i.value).FirstOrDefault() throws an exception?

Comment: @Aniket How would it do so? The only thing that can throw (after `Where`) is `double.Parse`.

Comment: double.Parse is where it can throw an exception :-)

Comment: @Aniket `double.Parse` was already included in the question, which means the OP assumes it will not throw. If this assumption is correct was not a part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

> I have statements like this all over the place.

Since you are doing this multiple times, you may want to improve efficiency, rather than reducing the line count. One way to approach this would be extracting all fields into a `Dictionary` at once, and then quickly taking the items as needed:

```
var fieldNames = new Set<string> {
    "Loan Amount", "Loan Balance", "Amount Due"
};
var dict = ll
    .Fields
    .Where(f => fieldNames.Contains(f.FieldTitle))
    .ToDictionary(f => f.FieldTitle, f => double.Parse(f.Value)); 
dict.TryGetValue("Loan Amount", out LatestItem.VelocifyLoanAmount);
dict.TryGetValue("Loan Balance", out LatestItem.VelocifyLoanBalance);
dict.TryGetValue("Amount Due", out LatestItem.VelocifyAmountDue);
```

Comment: Yes. This is an idea to try when they are the same type

Comment: @punkouter Right. Extracting items of different type is slightly trickier, but it can be done as well. Unfortunately, some wrapping of fields into `object`s would happen, but it could still be faster than multiple traversals of a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
var item = ll.Fields.Where(x = > x.FieldTitle == "Loan Amount").FirstOrDefault();
return (item != null) ? item.Value : DefaultReturnValue;
```

The return uses a tertiary operator. The first value is a boolean check. If the boolean is true then the value after the "?" is returned. Else, the value after the ":" is returned;

Comment: Why use `.Where()`. and `.FirstOrDefault()` here?

Comment: Good Point David. I was copying and pasting the code there, and failed to notice the redundancy there since I was focusing on the tertiary operator. You can do:

`var item = ll.Fields.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FieldTitle == "Loan Amount");`